# Store View Specific Widget

Tags: magento2, store-view, widget, new-products

Currently I have a New Product List widget running on my hompage with:

`{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget" display_type="all_products" products_count="10" template="product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}`

I have two stores atm, one for retail and one for wholesale. I do not want to display new products in retail store over at wholesale store and vice versa.

The products in both stores belong to different root categories. Is there an attribute such as

> store_view = "..retail.."

that I can include in the widget?

Answer (score 0):

Widget can be assign to specific storeview in widget/storefront properties